# How to store an image in a SQL Server database from Silverlight app?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, silverlight, image

I am trying to store some pictures into my SQL Server database from a Silverlight project, and I need some help, so my questions are:

1. How to convert an image to binary from a url to store it into my database (store all the image and not only the url)
2. Are there any other solutions, without passing by binary type? (since it exist the image type in SQL Server)
3. Finally, when the image is stored, how to read it from Silverlight?

Thank you in advance .

Comment: http://blog.farreachinc.com/2011/06/07/storing-files-in-sql-server-using-wcf-ria-services-and-silverlight-part-1/

Comment: Don't use the `IMAGE` type in SQL Server anymore - it's been deprecated since SQL Server 2005. Use `VARBINARY(MAX)` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.pitorque.de/MisterGoodcat/post/Storing-images-in-SQL-Server-with-RIA-Services.aspx

It is fully functional as in the user can select images from the local disk and upload them to the service where they are stored in the database. The user can retrieve a list of all images in the database and download them to the client for watching, and they can delete existing images from the database.

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to convert the `System.Drawing.Image` to a byte array and save the byte array to the database.

```
System.Drawing.Image image;
System.IO.MemoryStream imageStream;
byte[] imageBytes;

// image = your image object
imageStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
image.Save(imageStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg); // Use whatever format your image is.
imageBytes = imageStream.ToArray();
// Save imageBytes to a DB column of type VARBINARY(MAX)
```

To get the data back into an `System.Drawing.Image` object from a byte array use `System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(System.IO.Stream stream)`.

Comment: Unfortunately in SL4 the image control does not seem to have save as one of its methods

Answer (score 0):

- Download file contents and put into memory stream. See : http://www.csharp-examples.net/download-files/
- Add bytes from memory stream into database
- Get image with silverlight in C# by using the image class and method FromStream see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.aspx